# Advice on plotting a set of arrows in 3D

Tags: graphics3d

I have a data file composed of 5 columns (x, y, z, $\Delta$x, $\Delta$y). I'm using *Mathematica* to plot this data as arrows on a 3D surface. First of all, I generate a new table by summing columns 1 and 4, and 2 and 5, resulting in a dataset like (x, y, z, x+$\Delta$x, y+$\Delta$y), then I make the plot using the following command:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Arrowheads[.005], 
  Table[
    Arrow[{data[[n, {4, 5, 3}]], data[[n, {1, 2, 3}]]}], 
    {n, Length[data[[All, 1]]]}]}, 
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, .5}]
```

Which results in the following graphic:

[image]

First of all, the graphic is really heavy, which might not be surprising, because there are 1681 arrows in the plot. So, is there an easy way to skip some points? Also you can notice that some arrows are bigger than others, which seems to be related to the perspective. I don't know how to solve this other than reducing the size of the arrows, but then it becomes hard to see the features of the plot.

Any advice on how to make the plot look better or how to generate the plot in a better way will be very welcome.

I uploaded a sample data file fo those willing to try to plot it. The columns on the file correspond to (x, y, z, $\Delta$x, $\Delta$y), the 6th column can be ignored for the purposes of the present question. You can download the file in the link bellow.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr25i0xzd8rf2mx/test2.txt?dl=0

Comment: To exclude certain points you can use the syntax for table to take every nth element. i.e. `Table[i, {i,1,10,2}]` will give `{1,3,5,7,9}`. You might also look at something like a `StreamDensityPlot` where the arrows are drawn on a 2D plot with color indicating the z value.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Thank you for the tip, I could reduce the number of points using the suggested method. As for the use of `StreamDensityPlot`I'm afraid my data not always can be expressed as a vector field and Mathematica may produce wrong results interpolating it. But I'm currently trying out several ways to display this data and the concept behind `StreamDensityPlot` is very interesting, so I will try to do something similar.

Answer (score 4):

If you place your data in the proper format, you can use `VectorPlot3D` or `ListVectorPlot3D`.  It often helps to plot the two-dimensional surface (in semi-transparent style) as well.

```
myScalarField = Cos[x y] - z;
myVectorField = D[scalarField, {{x, y, z}}];
c = ContourPlot3D[
   myScalarField == 0, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
   Mesh -> None,
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5, Green]];
d = VectorPlot3D[myVectorField, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3},
   VectorPoints -> 25,
   VectorScale -> {0.1, Scaled[0.4]}, 
   RegionFunction -> 
      Function[{x, y, z}, - 0.1 <= myScalarField <= 0.1]];
   Show[c, d]
```

[image]

Comment: From what I've seem `VectorPlot`and similars generate better plots, but I'm afraid my data cannot be expressed by a vector field in some cases and Mathematica may produce wrong results interpolating it. Although, if I understood correctly, by using `VectorPoints->All` the vectors are just ploted and not interpolated. Is this right? Also I don't know how data should be formatted to work with `ListVectorPlot`. From some tests I've done it seems that Mathematica takes a vector from point {0,0,0} to {vx,vy,vz} and them moves it so it passes through the corresponding {x,y,z} point, right?

Comment: By the way, thank you for your suggestion of adding the surface to the plot. I'm actually plotting the surface as a separate graph but I will play around with this idea of combining them both.

Comment: If you make your data available, we can try to plot it.

Comment: Done. Check the link in the opening post.